# How to use google cloud functions in flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Now this is the **index.js** file

```
import 'dart:math';

// The Cloud Functions for Firebase SDK to create Cloud Functions and setup triggers.
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access Cloud Firestore.
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.getRandomNumbers=functions.https.onCall((num){

   const numbers=admin.firestore().collection('RandomNumbers').document('CurrentRandomNumber');
   return numbers.add({
   RandomNumber=new Random().nextInt(10);
   });

});
```

and the function to do the task

```
onPressed: (){
                CloudFunctions.instance.getHttpsCallable(

                    functionName: "getRandomNumbers",
                );
              },
```

Now as you can see I am trying to get a random number and add it to the firestore database but it is nor working neither showing any error. I am using android studio and I have installed all stuff as suggested in official doc.

Comment: If you are going to use functions.https.onCall you need to pass the parameter data, just I don't know what is the value of num  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#write_and_deploy_the_callable_function

Comment: I have an other error

Comment: 'PlatformException(functionsError, Cloud function failed with exception., {code: NOT_FOUND, details: null, message: NOT_FOUND})'

Comment: If possible help me out

Answer (score 1):

The Flutter code you shared doesn't actually call the Cloud Function yet. What you have now merely defines a reference to that Cloud Function. To call it, you'd do something like:

```
final HttpsCallable callable = CloudFunctions.instance.getHttpsCallable(
    functionName: 'getRandomNumbers',
);
dynamic response = await callable.call();
```

This is a pretty direct copy from the sample in the documentation on [using Cloud Functions in Flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_functions#usage), so I'd recommend keeping that handy while implementing it.

---

I noticed that your Cloud Function declaration looks unusual:

```
exports.getRandomNumbers=functions.https.onCall((num){
```

The examples in the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) follow this pattern:

```
exports.addMessage = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
```

So the arguments are always `data` and `context`, and any parameters you pass from your flutter code will be in the `data` argument.

For your current code it makes no difference, since you're not using any of the arguments, but I do recommend addressing this going forward.